# Custom static route not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

Hi I am trying to establish my project in react.
My Current project structure is

```
-public
--w
---dist
----bundle.js
---index.html
-server
--server.js
-src
--app.js
-webpack.config.js
-package.json
-.babelrc
```

I am using node js as server
I want my static files to called on `localhost:port//w/`
and api call on `localhost:port//api/`

I have tried manipulating `server.js`, routes, project structure and `webpack.config` but could not get success.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public/w');

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get('/w/*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Calling..');
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
})

app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on ${port}`);
})
```

webpack.config

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'w', 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                use: 'babel-loader', 
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'w'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
}
```

My routes

```
const AppRouter = (props) => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route path="/w/resume-builder" component={ResumeBuilder} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Can anyone suggest what should I do or What I am missing in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some restructure

```
-public
--dist
---bundle.js
--index.html
-server
--server.js
-src
--app.js
-webpack.config.js
-package.json
-.babelrc
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

//keep all api before fallback
app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
});

app.get('/w/*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Calling..');
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on ${port}`);
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                use: 'babel-loader', 
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
}
```

You can keep your routes same.