# Routes is changing the lookup location of resources

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

This post is extention to issue in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579725/custom-static-route-not-working). The previous problem was solved.

Everything was working fine till now when I added this route.

```
<Route path="/resume-builder/display" component={ResumeDisplay} />
```

I can visit this page via another page in the project when I refresh this page it shows error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/resume-builder/dist/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

display:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/resume-builder/dist/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I dont know why my page is looking for bundles on `/resume-builder/dist/bundle.js` where it is clearly metioned in `index.html` that it has to pick bundles from

```
<script src="./dist/bundle.js" ></script>
```

Does any one have any clue what is the issue and what could be slution to this?

Comment: set your script's source to '/dist/bundle.js'. This is an absolute path to your built bundle. Currently it's set to a relative one. This means that the browser will try to resolve it relative to the current URl path

Comment: it is already same

Comment: No, it's not the same. You shared `<script src="./dist/bundle.js" ></script>` to be in `index.html`. Is it still an issue when you update it to `<script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>`?

Comment: yes that thing worked. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Check your webpack file and add publicPath if not there as below.

```
 output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  }
```

Take help from below link.

https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/

Comment: can you explain it in short?

Comment: your code didnot worked. But thanx for the docs. I'll go through it

Comment: Is it help or still stuck?

Comment: I got the solution