# React Router: Allow path to be handled by server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, path, router

In our app, we have a need to have a route that is simply ignored by the router and handled by the server.  Specifically, we want any path that starts with /essais to be ignored by the app and passed on to the server.  How can I make that happen.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using `<Link to="/essais" target="_self">...</Link>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom static route not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579725/custom-static-route-not-working)

Comment: Please add some code behind what you are trying to do, so we have a better understanding.